# Error when using CefSharp.OffScreen in an ASP.Net Web Application - Could not load file or assembly CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.Core.DLL

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, cefsharp, cefsharp.offscreen

Is it possible to run CefSharp.OffScreen in an ASP.Net Web application? When I try this error happens right away and is before any code that I can put a breakpoint on. To get this error just create a new project, add the CefSharp.Offscreen package and then F5. I'm guessing I need to add some references or maybe it requires a STA thread? I realize this is probably not the typical use of this library but I am just experimenting.

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Could not load file or assembly 'CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.Core.DLL' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.Core.DLL' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below. 

Stack Trace: 


[FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.Core.DLL' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.]
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +0
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +37
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +159
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean forIntrospection) +80
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection) +22
   System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString) +29
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +39

[ConfigurationErrorsException: Could not load file or assembly 'CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.Core.DLL' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.]
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +777
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAllAssembliesFromAppDomainBinDirectory() +229
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssembly(AssemblyInfo ai) +140
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies(CompilationSection compConfig) +176
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetPreStartInitMethodsFromReferencedAssemblies() +99
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods(String preStartInitListPath, Boolean& isRefAssemblyLoaded) +310
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart() +165
   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +590

[HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load file or assembly 'CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.Core.DLL' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +10080656
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +99
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +263


Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.8.4075.0
```

Comment: Running a browser in progress in a web app isn't something I'd recommend, CEF in particular don't do well with the IIS application thread pool. CefSharp can be made to work,  there's a lot of hoops you'd have to jump through. Personally I'd suggest using puppeteer-sharp, where chromium is run as a separate process. If you want to to use CefSharp then running it in a service where you make requests through IPC works ok.

Comment: @amaitland Preaching to the choir like I said just experimenting I realize architecturally this is not ideal. What I am working on though is throwaway so if I can get it working it's gravy. Thanks for the tip I'll check out puppeteer-sharp.

Comment: I switched to puppeteer-sharp and it's working great. Leaving the question open in case someone has a solution for cefsharp.